Hide columns in worksheets based on selecting a cell from an InputBox
I developed a macro to hide all columns on all worksheets in current active workbook, if they are visible and unprotected.
Hiding is based on a cell value chosen from an InputBox.
Sub HideColumnsSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Choose the cell you want to hide columns in all visible unprotected sheets in this             workbook, based on the value of that cell."
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
      
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Select one cell :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    If InputRng = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Because the selected cell is empty, the macro was not executed.")
        GoTo 900 'Stop the macro because cell is empty
    End If
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = False Or ws.ProtectContents = True Then GoTo 100 
        'If the sheet is hidden or protected go to next sheet
        For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Cells
            If c.Value = InputRng Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next c
100:
    Next ws
   
900:

End Sub

An error message appears:

Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch

The error is related to:
If c.Value = InputRng Then



It's important to validate InputRng.
It's strongly advised to refrain from using Goto in structured coding.
Iterating through columns in the used range is more efficient than iterating through cells.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.CountLarge property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub HideColumnsSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim c As Range, vMch
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Choose the cell you want to hide columns in all visible unprotected sheets in this workbook, based on the value of that cell."
    On Error Resume Next
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Select one cell :", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If InputRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cancel InputBox
    If InputRng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then ' select multiple cells
        MsgBox "Please select ONE cell."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(InputRng.Value) = 0 Then ' blank cell
        MsgBox "Because the selected cell is empty, the macro was not executed."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If the sheet is hidden or protected go to next sheet
        If ws.Visible And (Not ws.ProtectContents) Then
            For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns ' loop through Cols
                vMch = Application.Match(InputRng.Value, c, 0) ' search target value
                If Not IsError(vMch) Then ' found
                    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub


@taller Just a side note: An equivalent to If Not IsError(vMch) Then is If IsNumeric(vMch) Then which might better indicate (for not so experienced users) that the result found in the positive case is a number than to negate an error.
